# Discrete Fourier series for a sum of deltas

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic

so Im given a discrete sum $$x[n] = \sum\limits_{r=\infty}^{+\infty}\delta[n-rN]$$
how do I calculate its discrete Fourier series coefficients?

Thank you.

edit: this is what i've come to up to now:[image]

Comment: is that the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) you mean?  are $n$ and $N$ integers?

Comment: yes sir, its kronecker delta

Comment: What happens if you apply the formula? (Read: please show us your work and where you're stuck).

Comment: i added a picture of where Im stuck.
As you can see, in line num 3, the sum within a sum of this delta by two indexes feels dependent.. so I dont know exactly how to proceede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta[n-rN]$ is a periodic Kronecker delta with period $N$, but the sum to get the fourier coefficients only "uses" one period $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N-1}$ so you don't have to worry about the periodic extension of $\delta$ and take just $x[n] = \delta[n]$ as your function. This is going to cancel out every exponential in the sum except when $n=0$, so the result will be independent of the particular coefficient and be just $a_k = 1/N$.

Comment: How do you cancel the sum that is within the outer sum? and get it to be delta[n]? except that I pretty much get it so thank you.

Comment: The inner sum doesn't affect the outer, so you can remove it. Why doesn't affect? Because it only changes the $rN$ term inside delta's time index, and the only way this could make some difference is when $n = rN$ (the condition for the delta function to be 1) but since the outer sum goes from $n = 0$ to $n = N-1$, $n$ is never going to be as big as $N$, so the $rN$ term won't change anything.

Comment: Thank you so much Eloi!
I find this forum very helpful for us the engineering students, where its hard to come by a community for engineering topics.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! Indeed this site is a nice place to learn, asking but also answering questions (I'm also a student of DSP right now). If you found my answer useful, you can vote or mark it as "accepted"!

Comment: up arrow from me.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the sequence $x[n]$ you'll see right away how it works. You have an impulse at $n=0$, at $n=-N$, at $n=N$, etc. But if you sum over only *one* period, no matter which period you choose, there's always only *one* impulse in that period. So you're left with only one sum index contributing to the final result. I'm sure you can take it from here.